# Ruby: `pop`ing of one array and `push`ing onto another

Tags: arrays, ruby

In Ruby, I want to `pop` an element (the smallest) off an array and `push` that *same* element on to a new array. I need it to be the same element that gets `push`'d, because I want to do it recursively without this happening:

```
a = [1,4,2,3,5,7,8,6]
b = []
b.push(a.min) #=> b = [1]
b.push(a.min) #=> b = [1,1]
b.push(a.min) #=> b = [1,1,1]
```

Rather than

```
b.push(a.min) #=> b = [1]
b.push(a.min) #=> b = [1,2]
b.push(a.min) #=> b = [1,2,3]
```

EDIT:

Should have mentioned, am trying not to use `sort`, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question requested a recursive method. None of the other answers are recursive.

Here is a recursive solution:

```
class Array
  def recursive_pop
    any? ? [delete(min)] + recursive_pop : []
  end
end

irb(main):082:0> original_array = [1,2,3]
  => [1, 2, 3]
irb(main):083:0> new_array = original_array.recursive_pop
  => [1, 2, 3]
irb(main):084:0> new_array
  => [1, 2, 3]
irb(main):085:0> original_array
  => []
```

As requested, the method removes the minimum element in the original array one by one and adds the element to the new array.

Comment: Mike, you pointed out that the OP wants to remove values from the original array and I did not do that in my answer. I'm sure you are right and thanks for pointing that out. I deleted my answer but may fix it and undelete

Comment: @CarySwoveland that is understandable. The question is pretty poorly worded so it looks ambiguous.

Comment: @Mike Ha, is it? I thought it was pretty explicit. How could I improve it?

Comment: @AdbA Even though the question mentioned recursive it sort of sounded like it was an extra word just thrown in, I wasn't totally sure if being recursive was a requirement at first. It would be more clear if you wrote the two requirements separately somehow. Such as: "I'm trying to accomplish two things. First, the element in the original array should be popped off when being added to the second array. Second, It should be done recursively."

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you could [`sort`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-sort) the initial array and then use the [`shift`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-shift) method to extract the first element.

```
a = [1,4,2,3,5,7,8,6].sort
b = []
b.push(a.shift) #=> b = [1]
b.push(a.shift) #=> b = [1,2]
b.push(a.shift) #=> b = [1,2,3]
```

Comment: This is not recursive.

Comment: would be good, but should have said trying specifically not to use sort.

Answer (score 1):

If it's strictly numerical you're looking for (or alphabetical), you can always just use array.sort.

`a = a.sort`

becomes

`a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]`.

Then

`b.push(a.shift)`

Answer (score 1):

With v.2.2+, you can use [Enumerable#min](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-min) with an argument:

```
def pop_n_push(arr, n)
  arr.min(n).each { |e| arr.delete_at(arr.index(e)) }.to_a
end

arr = [7,8,1,4,2,3,5,2,6]
new_arr = pop_n_push(arr, 4)
  #=> [1, 2, 2, 3] 
arr
  #=> [7, 8, 4, 5, 6]
```

`min` returns an enumerator containing the `n` smallest elements of `arr`. Each of those elements is located in and removed from `arr`. (Duplicate values are not a problem.) [Enumerator#each](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerator.html#method-i-each) returns its receiver, the enumerator, which is then converted to an array and returned by the method. One could instead write:

```
arr.min(n).to_a.each { |e| arr.delete_at(arr.index(e)) }
```

Note that this method preserves the order of the elements in `arr`. It should also be faster than sorting the array when `n` is substantially less than `arr.size`.

Comment: Should second line be `arr` instead of `a` and `n` instead of `3`?

Comment: The question asked for the element to be popped, but you said in your answer that `a` is unchanged. Popping it implies `a` should change.

Comment: Thanks, @sagarpandya82. I wrote this on a phone on which I could not run Ruby v2.2, so I couldn't test, which I almost always do. Still, it's a pretty bad oversight. I fixed that and also made some other changes.

Comment: @CarySwoveland If i had enough reps I would up vote this cause it really helped too, thanks!